# Pandas read_excel explicitly read a column in as text?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am reading in a bunch of columns from excel spreadsheets, a few of the fields are 'ID' codes which are text that looks like numbers (because they have leading zeros). I would like to keep these ID fields as text/strings, is there a way to either read everything in as text and the convert the number fields to numbers or explicitly read certain fields in as text/string?

Comment: Do you know how many columns there will be?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the `txt` proxy for a csv file

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """col1,col2,col3
1,01,a
2,02,b
3,03,c"""
```

Create a dictionary where keys are the ordinal positions of the columns and the values are the callables that are called on those columns.  The catch is that I need to know the number of columns.  Here, I know there are `3`.

```
converters = dict(enumerate([str] * 3))
print(converters)

{0: <class 'str'>, 1: <class 'str'>, 2: <class 'str'>}
```

Then we pass that to `pd.read_csv`

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), converters=converters)

print(df)

  col1 col2 col3
0    1   01    a
1    2   02    b
2    3   03    c
```

And

```
print(df.dtypes)

col1    object
col2    object
col3    object
dtype: object
```